# How do I connect to available networks from the command-line?

Tags: networking, command-line, dhcp

More accurately, how do I tell Ubuntu to obtain an address using DHCP for all the network interfaces it finds (which do not require a password)?

Comment: [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic) may interest you. (Perhaps someone can write an answer with more detail about that, or add it to an existing answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifconfig -a
```

lists all the network interfaces, so you can run

```
ifconfig -a | grep --only-matching -i "^\w\+" | xargs -l1 sudo dhclient
```

whenever you want to connect to a network.

If you would like it to happen when you log in, simply append it to the file `~/.bashrc` (for you only) or `/etc/bash.bashrc` (globally).